# Cassandra installation 'module' object has no attribute 'decompress

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, ubuntu-19.04

After installing Cassandra 3.11 version on ubuntu 19.04 I am getting the following error once I fire command `cqlsh`

```
root@dnilesh:/etc/cassandra# cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': ProtocolError('Unexpected response during Connection setup: AttributeError("\'module\' object has no attribute \'decompress\'",)',)})
```

Cassandra service is up and running but not able to connect cqlsh terminal.

Comment: Worked by this commad : export CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=true

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked:

```
$ export CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=true
$ cqlsh
```

After the last cqlsh there was a problem with missing cassandra-driver, and installing through sudo pip... didn't work I had to switch to root user!

```
$ sudo su
# pip install cassandra-driver
# cqlsh
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `cqlsh [ip address]` (replace the brackets with the IP address of the host) or `cqlsh $(hostname)` (no substitutions are needed)